# Как на html сделать блок, который нельзя перемотать?

Tags: html

div должен оставаться в центре экрана по высоте, но по краям по ширине, и его нельзя перемотать. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: "А сегодня в завтрашний день не все могут смотреть. Вернее смотреть могут не только лишь все, мало кто может это делать". Именно так читается ваш вопрос. Смысл не понятен. Исправьте его, добавьте больше конкретики

Answer (score 1):

Перемотать? Если вы имеете ввиду чтобы он был всегда по центру экрана, при скролле странице. То задайте блоку `position: fixed;`